# Predictive Posterior

Tags: distributions, bayesian

I have the following

$$x\sim NegativeBinomial(r,\theta)$$

$$\theta \sim beta(a,b)$$

and proved that posterior is

$$\theta|x \sim beta(\sum x_{i} +a,nr+b)$$

I would like to find the posterior predictive distribution so I calculate 
$$f(y|x)=\int_{0}^{1} f(y|\theta)p(\theta|x)d\theta$$
which is equal to 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
y+r-1\\ 
y
\end{pmatrix}\frac{B(\sum x_{i}+a+y,r+nr+b)}{B(\sum x_{i}+a,nr+b)}$$

and I don't truly know which distribution is this , but it seems similar to Beta-Binomial.

Any idea or help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a distribution called a "Beta Negative Binomial" distribution, which properties are [described on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_negative_binomial_distribution), which corresponds to this case. Its main properties are described on this page, but I wonder how useful it is to give it a name.